How to add a common module to examples in Rust?
I have 2 binaries in examples folder: example1_main.rs, example2_main.rs. How do I add a common module example_common.rs that could be used by all example programs? and how to import them?
The files layout is like this:
src: ...
examples
|- example1_main.rs
|- example2_main.rs
|- example_common1.rs (how to add common modules and import them in *_main.rs?)
|- example_common2.rs


You can use the include! macro, which copies the source code, instead of a normal use statement:
// examples/example_main.rs

include!("./common.rs");

pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", library::add(common::double(2), 2)); // 6
}

// examples/common.rs

mod common {
    pub fn double(x: u64) -> u64 {
        x * 2
    }
}

// src/lib.rs

pub fn add(left: u64, right: u64) -> u64 {
    left + right
}


The Cargo Book describes the file layout for examples as such:
⋮
├── examples/
│   ├── simple.rs
│   └── multi-file-example/
│       ├── main.rs
│       └── ex_module.rs
⋮

For a subdirectory to be recognized as a multi-file example, it needs to have a main.rs file. This means that we can put common modules in a subdirectory that doesn't have a main.rs file and Cargo won't try to compile the files in that subdirectory as a standalone example.
I'd reorganize your files this way:
examples/
|- example1.rs
|- example2.rs
|- common/
   |- common1.rs
   |- common2.rs
   |- mod.rs

common/mod.rs would contain:
#![allow(dead_code)]

mod common1;
mod common2;

Then in each of your examples, you'd use mod common; to include the common modules and reference the modules as common::common1 and common::common2.
In a project where I used this layout, I put #![allow(dead_code)] in common/mod.rs because not all examples used everything from the common modules. Since the common modules will be recompiled in each example, the compiler will report dead code warnings as appropriate for each example, unless we explicitly allow dead code in the common modules.
You could also organize the examples as multi-file examples, but then to reference the common module, you'd have to use a #[path] attribute to instruct the compiler to look for the module one level higher.
#[path = "../common/mod.rs"]
mod common;

